# Old Cyberpunk MacroMind animation

Tags: story-identification, character-identification

When I was a kid in the mid 80's to early 90's, I somehow got some short (less than 1 minute), 1-bit animations on my Macintosh computer. These may have been samples that came with the VideoWorks or Director software packages. The one I'm thinking of portrayed a pretty cool looking flying car/craft. I recall we could also see a male character and there was a pretty solid cyberpunk style. There was a funky (for the digital samples available) beat that went along with it. What's especially intriguing is the animation seemed to be advertising some fictional universe (as if, for example, it was based on a comic.)

If you remember this, do you remember what it was called? Or if it was based on a comic/story? I have combed YouTube and Google Images for this, but to no avail. I maintain some hope because the platform was still pretty new and there were not a ton of animations out there at that time.

Comment: This sorta thing; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r89JuteeZBg

Comment: @Valorum alas no.  Those are for a production company named VideoWorks.  This post is about an old bit of Mac software called VideoWorks (which then changed its name to Director -- and I don't know which version made this sample)

Comment: Do any of the CDs in these eBay listings look familiar, maybe as somewhere you could have got these from? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/175583453704 and https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/225438590232 or https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/266148362874 or https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/385398458148 or https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/125335097204 or https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/265241321292

Comment: Male character, flying car, "some fictional universe... based on a comic". Could it have been [Dick Tracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Tracy#Space_period)? Note that the Wikipedia article mentions a period in the 60s where *"After an eventual sharing of technological information, Moon technology became standard issue on Tracy's police force, including air cars, flying cylindrical vehicles."*